# Spark HiveContext : Spark Engine OR Hive Engine?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hivecontext

I am trying to understand spark `hiveContext`.
when we write query using `hiveContext` like

```
sqlContext=new HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql("select * from TableA inner join TableB on ( a=b) ")
```

Is it using Spark Engine OR Hive  Engine?? I believe above query get executed with Spark Engine. But if thats the case why we need dataframes?

We can blindly copy  all hive queries in `sqlContext.sql("")` and run without using dataframes.

By DataFrames, I mean like this `TableA.join(TableB, a === b)`
We can even perform aggregation using SQL commands. Could any one Please clarify the concept? If there is any advantage of using dataframe joins rather that `sqlContext.sql()` join?
join is just an example. :)

Comment: SQL is a query language, that must be compiled by the query processor. The Dataframe API is a (kind of) query language, just more complicated for a human to read/write, but easier for the query processor.

Comment: Note that some expressions will process a bit faster when written in SQL because the Lambda expressions in Scala are implemented with lots of boilerplate conversions and controls (cf. recent presentations at Spark Summit).

Comment: Note also that when writing into Hive tables, a SQL `INSERT` will make sure that the file format strictly honors the Hive structure, which is not always the case otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Spark HiveContext uses Spark execution engine underneath see the [spark code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveContext.scala#L84).

Parser support in spark is pluggable, HiveContext uses spark's HiveQuery parser.

Functionally you can do everything with sql and Dataframes are not needed. But dataframes provided a convenient way to achieve the same results. The user doesn't need to write a SQL statement.

Comment: So in short  can I say "Functionally and Performance wise " there is no difference if I use "SQL" OR "dataFrame"  and its just about user convenience ??  and "SQL" has to go through Query parser and "Dataframe" doesnt have to?

Comment: @rohan nayak Right

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification